# sqlite3 xcode libsqlite3.dylib

Tags: frameworks, sqlite, ios-simulator, xcode3.2

I have an error in my projet: sqlit3_open and sqlite_close symbol not found.
please how can I resolve this problem.

I added the framework libsqlite3.dylib and the header #import "sqlite3.h".
the problem persist.

please my english is very bad, done make atention

thank all

Answer (score 1):

here is good example of sqlite3 use in ios

http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/08/19/iphone-programming-tutorial-creating-a-todo-list-using-sqlite-part-1/

check this.

Comment: your link is good. but it n't resolve my problem. I done no if the problem is my Osx version and my SDK. I use osx 10.5.8 xcode 3.1.2 and iphone simulator 2.2.1. have you an idea. thank

Comment: ld warning: in /install/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib, file is not of required architecture
ld warning: in /install/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk/usr/lib/libsqlite3.0.dylib, file is not of required architecture

Comment: Undefined symbols:
  "_sqlite3_open", referenced from:
      -[LiteSqlViewController openDB] in LiteSqlViewController.o
  "_sqlite3_close", referenced from:
      -[LiteSqlViewController openDB] in LiteSqlViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
    "_sqlite3_open", referenced from:
        -[LiteSqlViewController openDB] in LiteSqlViewController.o
    "_sqlite3_close", referenced from:
        -[LiteSqlViewController openDB] in LiteSqlViewController.o
  ld: symbol(s) not found
  collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Build failed (2 errors)